# Use Perl module only when it is needed within a subroutine

Tags: perl, require, perl-module

Imagine my script has these two subs

```
sub with_json_mod{
    use JSON::Tiny;
    blah blah blah;
}

sub without_json_mod{
   blah blah blah;
}
```

I only want to use `without_json_mod` when `JSON::Tiny` is not installed.

How can I make Perl not fail if `JSON::Tiny` is not installed and, instead, use the `without_json_mod` sub instead?

I tried to call `require` in the `with_json_mod` and it seems to work, but it doesn't work when I try to make it import the `encode_json` sub as in

```
sub with_json_mod{
    require JSON::Tiny qw/encode_json/;
    blah blah blah;
}
```

Comment: `eval "use Module; 1"?`

Comment: I think that eval would suffer, because `use` is a compile time thing.

Comment: True yes, I was thinking of testing it with `eval` but commented to quickly, you have it perfectly summed up in the answer though. @Sobrique

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's because you're calling `require` incorrectly.

What you need is:

```
require JSON::Tiny;
JSON::Tiny -> import ( 'encode_json' );
```

You can wrap that in an 'eval' too, and test the value of `$@`:

```
eval { require JSON::Tiny; };
warn $@ if $@;
```

Answer (score 6):

There are two main differences between `use` and `require`.

1. `use` happens at compile time and `require` happens at runtime.
2. `use` calls the `import()` method in the loaded package (if one exists) and `require` doesn't.

So you need to add a call to `import()`.

```
sub with_json_mod{
    require JSON::Tiny;
    JSON::Tiny->import('encode_json');
    blah blah blah;
}
```